# What's the logic behind the order the elements are passed to a comparison function in std::sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, std, strict-weak-ordering

I'm practicing lambdas:

```
 int main()
 {
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4};
    int count = 0;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int& a, const int& b) -> bool
        {
        return a > b;
        });
  }
```

This is just code from GeeksForGeeks to sort in descending order, nothing special. I added some print statements (but took them out for this post) to see what was going on inside the lambda. They print the entire vector, and the `a` and `b` values:

```
1 2 3 4  
a=2 b=1

2 1 3 4  
a=3 b=2

3 2 1 4  
a=4 b=3

4 3 2 1 <- final
```

So my more detailed question is: 
What's the logic behind the order the vector elements are being passed into the `a` and `b` parameters?

Is `b` permanently at index `0` while `a` is iterating? And if so, isn't it a bit odd that the *second* param passed to the lambda stays at the *first* element? Is it compiler-specific? Thanks!

Comment: The order depends on the sort algorithm that is used by the std library. So you can never know in which order they are called if you don't know which algorithm is used.

Comment: Why the `const int&` parameters?

Comment: That's just how it was on geeksforgeeks.  I'm guessing they were just being tidy or something. In a real situation the lambda could be altering 'a' or 'b' so const is out.  Not sure about the reference though. @curiousguy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing a *predicate* to `std::sort()`, you are specifying your *sorting criterion*. The predicate must return `true` if the first parameter (i.e., `a`) *precedes* the second one (i.e., `b`), for the sorting criterion you are specifying.

Therefore, for your predicate:

```
return a > b;
```

If `a` is *greater* than `b`, then `a` will *precede* `b`.

---

> So my more detailed question is: What's the logic behind the order the vector elements are being passed into the `a` and `b` parameters?

`a` and `b` are just pairs of elements of the elements you are passing to `std::sort()`. The "logic" will depend on the underlying algorithm that `std::sort()` implements. The pairs may also differ for calls with identical input due to randomization.

Answer (score 1):

> Is 'b' permanently at index 0 while 'a' is iterating? And if so, isn't it a bit odd that the second param passed to the lambda stays at the first element?

No, because the first element is the higher.

Seems that, with this algorithm, all elements are checked (and maybe switched) with the higher one (at first round) and the higher one is placed in first position; so `b` ever points to the higher one.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Then my question becomes if 'a' and 'b' are assigned (by std::sort) based on which is greater, why have the comparison return statement at all?

Comment: @RyanA - The point is that `b` is fixed to the greather (found at the moment) and `a` is the possible alternative (first time point to `v[1]`, second time to `v[2]`, third time to `v[3]`); the returned value is important because if `true`, the list is reordered.

Comment: That's a great clarification! Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio, std::sort uses insertion sort if the sub-array size is <= 32 elements. For a larger sub-array, it uses intro sort, which is quick sort unless the "recursion" depth gets too deep, in which case it switches to heap sort. The output you program produces appears to correspond to some variation of insertion sort. Since the compare function is "less than", and since insertion sort is looking for out of order due to left values "greater than" right values, the input parameters are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

You just compare two elements, with a given ordering. This means that if the order is `a` and then `b`, then the lambda must return `true`.

The fact that `a` or `b` are the first or the last element of the array, or fixed, depends on the sorting algorithm and of course of your data!

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Are you saying that the lambda variables 'a' and 'b' are assigned vector elements based on whichever is greater (always 'a' in this one)?  Thus this lambda will always return true because 'a' will always be greater than 'b'?

Comment: No, I m saying that the lambda creates an ordering in the data. What it is assigned, as a value, depends on your data and the sorting algorithm.